# Convergence/Divergence of $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^k}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

> I am trying to understand for what values of $k$ does the definite integral $$I_k=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^k}\,dx$$ converge or diverge.

So far, I was able to prove that for $k<0.5$, $I_k$ diverges, as follows:

$$I_k > \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{k}{\sqrt{1+k^2}} \dfrac{1}{(1+x^2)^k}\,dx$$

Then a change of variables $s=1+k^2$, one can reduce the R.H.S to $\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{s^{k+0.5}}\,ds$. This proves RHS diverges if $k<0.5$.

However, I am unable to decide/prove the case for $k>0.5$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Write $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^k}\,dx=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^k}\,dx+\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^k}\,dx$$

Then, use the estimate for $k> 1/2$

$$\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^k}\le \frac{1}{x^{2k}}$$

---

For $0\le k\le 1/2$, we simply note that for $x\ge 1$,

$$\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^k}\ge \frac{1}{(2x^2)^k}$$

Comment: This, coupled with the fact that the OP already knows it diverges for $k<1/2$, should be perfect.  (+1)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thank you my friend!  Much appreciated!

Comment: And the case $k=1/2$, to be complete?

Comment: @bernard I have edited to account for the case $k\le 1/2$.